# Python dataclasses: Allow mutation of existing field but disallow new fields

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I would like to write a dataclass that allows change of value for fields that already exist, but prevent addition of new fields.

I am on Python >= 3.10

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: int
    baz: int

foo = Foo(bar=1, baz=0)
foo.baz = 2 # this should be okay
foo.qux = 'hey' # I want this to throw error
```

Setting `@dataclass(frozen=True)` cannot achieve my goal as it would also prevent mutation of values.
How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `slots=True` , it is similiar as using `__slots__` [dataclasses slots](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

```
@dataclass(slots=True)
class Foo:
    bar: int
    baz: int
```

Comment: I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. Thank you!

Comment: probably yes, hope this solve your problem